# Class variable in Rails persisting on browser refresh

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails after coming from a long PHP background. I'm getting a weird error thats got me stumped.

I have a class variable set up like so:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    @@customTags = []

    def self.addCustomGA(slot, name, value, scope=3)
        h = {:slot => slot, :name => name, :value => value, :scope => scope}
        @@customTags.push h

    end

    def self.customTagOutput

        tags = ""
        @@customTags.each do |ct|
        tags << "_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', "+ct[:slot].to_s+", '"+ct[:name].to_s+"', '"+ct[:value].to_s+"', "+ct[:scope].to_s+"]);\n"
        end
        tags
    end

end
```

I am running a little test in my controller that calls:

```
Article.addCustomGA(1, 'categories', @article.category_list);
```

And then in my HAML view I'm outputting the content like so:

```
#{Article.customTagOutput}
```

This works great on the first go. But when I refresh the page it keeps adding an entry to the array - so the `@@customTags` array seems to be persisting across my session! If I don't refresh for a few minutes then it resets itself.

My first thought was some kind of caching thing happening, but Google hasn't turned up anything for me.

Comment: I would recommend against putting view code in your model. Define a helper for the relevant controller instead.

Comment: Correctly me if I am mistaken, but are you simply looking to use an instance variable instead of a class variable (i.e. `@customTags` would only persist in a single instance of an object and hence if you were to refresh the page and instance of the object would be created.)

Comment: My problem is that I need to add items across multiple instances of Article, so I made is a class variable instead

Comment: @Alex OK I will look into using a helper instead. I was using ApplicationHelper and noticed the same behavior btw

Comment: @MarkDavies don't use class variables! see my updated answer. If this is something that applies to all `Article`s, hard-code it! If it applies to individual articles, store it.

Comment: @Alex OK I think that makes sense - can you explain what you mean by hard coding it into the app?

Comment: Say I have some google analytics code that applies to all articles, shove it in a javascript file instead of generating it on the fly. Why would you need to change it while the app is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't store anything in a class variable in your model. Class variables are generally a bad idea. This looks like it should really be done in a view helper method in the helpers file for the relevant controller (something like `app/helpers/articles_helper.rb`).

You shouldn't need to store anything like this for the entire model class. You either store data for each instance, or you hard-code it into the app.

The reason that variable is kept between refreshes is that Rails loads the `Article` class once (on startup) and the class variable doesn't get re-created (since the class doesn't get reloaded).

Answer (score 1):

Consider simply using an *instance* variable instead of a *class* variable, `@customTags` would only persist only in a *single instance* of an object of that class and hence if you were to refresh the page an new instance of the object of that class would be created and contain no previous values).

On another note, it's generally considered poor practice to define a variable like this in your model, consider putting in the according helper file.